# get EmailIds with same AdminId for a particular SubsId

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows in Sql server & I need to get EmailIds with same AdminId for a particular SubsId, Can some one suggest me some better way?

```
MAPPING table
     SubsId   AdminId    EmailId
       1         1         1
       1         1         2
       1         2         3
       1         2         2
       2         2         2
```

I need to get EmailIds with same AdminId for a particular SubsId (say 1). I am doing this way, Is there any better way?

```
 public class Mapping
 {
   public int SubsId {get; set;}
   public int AdminId {get; set;}
   public List<int> LstEmailId {get; set;}
 }

 SELECT distinct(ADMINID) FROM MAPPING WHERE SUBSID = 1.
```

Execute this query get the returned admin ids in a list of int,then loop through all the admin ids in the list. Let's say AdminIds are in a List LstAdminIds then

```
 var ObjLstMapping = new List<Mapping>();
 foreach(AdminId in LstAdminIds )
 {
     var LstEmailIds = List<int>();
     SELECT EMAILID FROM MAPPING WHERE SUBSID=1 AND ADMINID = AdminId
     // execute this query which will return a set of rows. Loop through each row & add to the list LstEmailIds 
    while(ObjSqldataReader.Read())
    {
       LstEmailIds.Add(Convert.Tont32(ObjSqldataReader["EMAILID"]))
    }
    ObjLstMapping. Add(new Mapping
    {
        SubsId = 1,
        AdminId = AdminId,
        LstEmailId = LstEmailIds 
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can more easily get this answer by utilizing SQL Server.  (This is the kind of thing it was made to do.)  Try replacing your query:

```
SELECT distinct(ADMINID) FROM MAPPING WHERE SUBSID = 1
```

with this:

```
SELECT * FROM MAPPING WHERE SUBSID = 1 AND EmailId = AdminId
```

(Ideally, you should avoid using "Select *" and actually list out your columns explicitly.  This is good practice and helps to avoid errors if the table structure changes.)  Changing your query should give you the results without having to do any post-processing of your data in your C# application.